# JavaFX Modular project issues

Tags: javafx, gluon-mobile

I have Gluon Mobile sample project and decided to make it modular by adding `module-info.java` class, anyway since then I'm receiving many package errors like:

```
error: package com.gluonhq.attach.util.impl is not visible
package com.gluonhq.attach.util.impl is declared in module com.gluonhq.attach.util, which does not export it
package com.sun.javafx is declared in module javafx.base, which does not export it to module Simple
package com.sun.javafx is not visible
package com.sun.javafx is declared in module javafx.base, which does not export it to module Simple
...
```

The problem started since I added this following snippet code, in`main()` method:

```
if(isWindows() || isMac() || isUnix()) {
            System.setProperty("javafx.platform" , "Desktop");
        }

        // define service for desktop
        StorageService storageService = new StorageService() {
            @Override
            public Optional<File> getPrivateStorage() {
                // user home app config location (linux: /home/[yourname]/.gluonmaps)
                return Optional.of(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
            }

            @Override
            public Optional<File> getPublicStorage(String subdirectory) {
                // this should work on desktop systems because home path is public
                return getPrivateStorage();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
                //noinspection ConstantConditions
                return getPrivateStorage().get().canWrite();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
                //noinspection ConstantConditions
                return getPrivateStorage().get().canRead();
            }
        };

        // define service factory for desktop
        ServiceFactory<StorageService> storageServiceFactory = new ServiceFactory<StorageService>() {

            @Override
            public Class<StorageService> getServiceType() {
                return StorageService.class;
            }

            @Override
            public Optional<StorageService> getInstance() {
                return Optional.of(storageService);
            }

        };
        // register service
        Services.registerServiceFactory(storageServiceFactory);
```

It is supposed to solve this, and avoid little things that can become great problems latter:

```
Sep 21, 2020 2:09:35 PM com.gluonhq.attach.util.Platform <clinit>
INFO: javafx.platform is not defined. Desktop will be assumed by default.
```

Pls, help!

Comment: For starters, you shouldn't use private API like `com.sun.javafx.PlatformUtil.isMac`. Then that warning about `javafx.platform` is just an indication that you are running on desktop, there is no need to set the system property. For mobile, it will be set to iOS or Android. Also there is Attach StorageService for [desktop](https://github.com/gluonhq/attach/blob/master/modules/storage/src/main/java/com/gluonhq/attach/storage/impl/DesktopStorageService.java), so I'm not sure why you need to implement it yourself.

Comment: Oh! Thanks, I Guess it was a small misunderstanding.